# What is the notation of recursive relation in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, oracle11g, foreign-keys

I cannot find the solution on the web. I am wondering how I write the recursive relation in oracle. At the moment this is what I got:

```
create table medewerkers
(medewerker_ID          varchar(15)  primary key,
naam                    varchar(50) not null,
adres                   varchar(50) not null,
telefoon_nummer         varchar(10) not null,
salaris                 number(4)   not null,
functie                 varchar(50) not null,

manager                 varchar(15) constraint FK_Manager references medewerkers (medewerker_ID) on delete cascade,
werknemer_winkel_nummer number(15)  constraint FK_W_winkel references winkel (winkel_nummer) on delete cascade,
constraint check_salaris check (salaris < 3000)
);
```

at the moment I created a manager column as FK for this recursive relation. I did not create an extra table because I am told that if they are 1-to-many with employee then I could place the FK within the table.

Now I am inserting a value like this one:

```
insert into MEDEWERKERS (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
values(11159112, 'Joost', 'Eindhoven Langloopstraat 1', 0678765478, 1500, 'baliemedewerker', 10, 'nee');
```

Oracle db gives an error back:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MAXIME.FK_MANAGER) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
```

How am I else supposed to get values into the manager column?

I hope my question is not too vague.

Comment: You are expected to insert the row with `medewerker_ID`='nee' before trying to insert a row that has 'nee' as its manager.  That's what the foreign key constraint enforces.  If you must insert out of order you could make the constraint `deferrable`.

Comment: That was exactly the awnser that I was looking for! Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the manager is there before you add their underlings.

The CEO/Manager/Owner can be added with a `NULL` manager:

```
INSERT INTO MEDEWERKERS (medewerker_id, naam, adres, telefoon_nummer, salaris, functie, werknemer_winkel_nummer, manager)
VALUES ( 'nee', 'The Boss Man', 'Home Office', '0000000001', 9999, 'Owner', 10, NULL );
```

The employees can then be added with the correct foreign key references (as per the OP).

Also - if you are entering telephone numbers with a leading 0 then you probably want to wrap the data in quotes `''` otherwise you may find that the conversion from number to varchar will lose it.

[As an aside: do you really want `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the foreign keys? If you delete a manager then all their employees will be deleted as well.]

Comment: you are correct! Tony andrews provided the awnser first, but your explanation is the same. I mark your awnser as the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question was perfectly formed.

Have you considered temporarily disabling the FK_Manager constraint so you can add the top-level of management?  Then enable the constraint while you add the next level down of employees?

Just a thought.

Comment: Tony Andrews provided me with the right awnser. Thanks for your reply though

Comment: Yes, using deferred is the better solution.  Oh well!